delay block: total pivoting and singular matrix problem
I am working on a larger model in OpenModelica and I keep getting this error:
Failed to solve linear system of equations (no. 5) at time 0.000000, system is singular for U[2, 2].
The default linear solver fails, the fallback solver with total pivoting is started at time 0.000000. That might raise performance issues, for more information use -lv LOG_LS.
Matrix singular!

The initialization finished successfully without homotopy method.
### STATISTICS ###
The simulation finished successfully.

As you can see, the solver is changed automatically and then it runs.
I made a MWE which still throws the error, you can find it below.
If I only simulate a delay block and connect its input to its output, it results in a matrix singular error without finishing the simulation.
What is the difference here? Why does the MWE only simulate after changing to a "total pivoting" solver?
This example is a little piece taken from a standard model and normally should work.
Any ideas or hints, anybody?
Thanks and best regards

(I may not post images because of lack of reputation, apparently. but the code is below, including graphical annotations)
model mwe 
  
  Modelica.Blocks.Nonlinear.FixedDelay fixedDelay(delayTime = 1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {10, -80}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.BooleanConstant booleanConstant(k = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-128, -40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const7(k = 1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-88, -22}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Logical.Switch switch18 annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-30, -40}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

equation
  connect(switch18.u2, booleanConstant.y) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-42, -40}, {-117, -40}}, color = {255, 0, 255}));
  connect(switch18.y, fixedDelay.u) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-19, -40}, {60, -40}, {60, -80}, {22, -80}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(fixedDelay.y, switch18.u3) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-1, -80}, {-60, -80}, {-60, -48}, {-42, -48}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(const7.y, switch18.u1) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-77, -22}, {-60, -22}, {-60, -32}, {-42, -32}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  
annotation(
    preferredView = "diagram",
    Icon(graphics = {Rectangle(fillColor = {255, 255, 255}, fillPattern = FillPattern.Solid, extent = {{-100, 100}, {100, -100}}), Text(origin = {6, 25}, extent = {{-52, 59}, {42, -47}}, textString = "Delay"), Text(origin = {-2, -31}, extent = {{-38, 45}, {42, -47}}, textString = "Flag")}, coordinateSystem(initialScale = 0.1)));
end mwe;

I am expecting the model to just compile and run -- and to understand what the problem is here.
I tried setting
initial equation 
    fixedDelay.y = 1;

but that didn't help.

Whats an "MWE"?

a Minimal Working Example (not strictly "working" here, but it isolates the issue out of a larger model.)

Note that it just runs in Dymola. If you vary it to have the switch actually switching and a sine-source instead of the boolean constant you will then get a non-linear system unless you set Advanced.Modelica.BreakDelayLoops. So it seems OpenModelica specific

Hey Hans Olsson, thank you for checking. Could you explain what you mean by breakdelayloops?

Without the break delay loops flag Dymola assumes that the delay is so short that changing the input (in a system of equations) can impact the output.
